Subtracting a very small number from a float
The smallest number that differentiates two float values is FLT_EPSILON, which is defined as:
#define FLT_EPSILON 1.19209290E-07F // decimal constant

(Yes I am aware of this: https://frama-c.com/2013/05/09/Definition-of-FLT_EPSILON.html)
However, upon subtracting a very small number (1e-12) from a zero, I would expect the resulting number to be zero, also considering it is less than half way mark of FLT_EPSILON.
However, the following program outputs:

Value of EPSILONF: -0.000000000001000

#include <stdio.h>
    
#define EPSILONF static_cast<float>(1e-12)
    
int main() {
    printf("Value of EPSILONF: %.15f\n", float(0.0f-EPSILONF));
    return 0;
}

What am I missing here?

FLOAT_EPSILON is actually defines as the difference between 1.0 and the smallest number greater than 1.0 that is representable by a float.  When dealing with numbers smaller than one, they can have a difference that is considerably less than FLOAT_EPSILON

%f is format specifier for double type, not for float. I'm not sure if there exists any specifier for float...

@Yksisarvinen there isn't one.  A float gets converted to a double in a variadic parameter list (same with std::ostream::operator<<(float), for that matter).

@ChrisDodd Thanks much! I assumed that FLT_EPSILON would be the "increments" across the floats. I tested it with 1.0f + EPSILONF which resulted in 1.0. So what is the epsilon for values below 1.0f ? Any reading material would be appreciated.

@RemyLebeau Didn't know that, thanks

@SKPS As you get closer to 0 the epsilon gets smaller, that’s how floating point works. Check Wikipedia for an overview. Picture floating point like the binary version of writing a number in scientific notation and then truncating the multiplier so you’re only taking N sig figs.

Raw epsilon for any value 1.MeP   is ~FLT_EPSILON * 1eP. For 0 it's ~1e-38.

Sometimes useful to print out the entire number cout << std::setprecision(2048) << std::fixed << num << "\n"; (Could also add code to trim the excessive trailing zeros).

Might be useful: std::nextafter returns the next representable floating-point value after the floating-point value given as its first argument. The second argument specifies the direction to go (up or down).


The smallest number that differentiates two float values is FLT_EPSILON

What you are missing is that this isn't what FLT_EPSILON is. FLT_EPSILON is the difference between 1.0 and the next representable number greater than 1.0.
Once the absolute value gets close to 0 you get into the range of subnormal numbers (see page 19), where the differences between two consecutive representable numbers are significantly smaller than FLT_EPSILON.
The difference (effectively) between 0.0 and the next greatest representable number is FLT_MIN. For a 32-bit IEEE floating-point it's 2-149.
Btw, for doubles, the constants are DBL_EPSILON and DBL_MIN.

Numbers less than 1.0 are not subnormal -- they're still normal numbers.  Denorms (the usual term) are numbers that would require an exponent less than the minimal representable.
